# Mysql innodb - Crashed recovery help

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, mysqldump

It is really painful our mysql wp db crashed!

I backed up /var/lib/mysql and tried `innodb_force_recovery` up to value 4. But no luck

When I try backing up using mysqldump it loses connection while dumping random row from wp_posts

mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `pq_posts` at row: 27571

When I login to phpmyadmin it crashes randomly and shows correct number of rows `(271099 total)` on the first page of table list (pq_posts) but crashes when clicking to the next page.

[image]

my system has 16GB memory and has 6 cores. but at present memory almost consumed and `free -m` shows only

```
root@localhost:~# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16040       15754         136          97         149          79
Swap:           511         511           0
```

Is that a memory issue? Is it ok to clear ram at this stage using `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` ?

Can I restart server? or is there anything to be done before restarting ?

mysql.conf

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size     = 16M
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
skip-name-resolve
default-storage-engine=InnoDB

max_allowed_packet=1024M
max_connections = 256
net_read_timeout = 7200
net_write_timeout = 7200
#innodb_force_recovery = 4
#timeout
interactive_timeout=7200
wait_timeout=7200

innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 6 
innodb_log_file_size = 512M 
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_open_files=5000
innodb_io_capacity_max=4000
innodb_old_blocks_time=2000

sort_buffer_size = 384K #mysqltuner 
open_files_limit=50000
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_min_res_unit = 512K
query_cache_limit = 2M #8M 
query_cache_size = 128M #512 mysqltuner suggested >64M

innodb_lru_scan_depth=256
innodb_io_capacity=3500 
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5 
read_buffer_size=256K  
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K 
tmp_table_size= 256M
max_heap_table_size= 256M
thread_stack = 128K
thread_cache_size = 32

slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=1024M
```

NB: If anyone ready to personally assist for recovery that can also be discussed. This is live db and Im desperate.

MYsql Log

```
2022-11-09T14:32:47.750249Z 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 5000 (request: 50000)
2022-11-09T14:32:47.934385Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2022-11-09T14:32:47.935901Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2-log) starting as process 15742 ...
2022-11-09T14:32:47.940290Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2022-11-09T14:32:47.940308Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-11-09T14:32:47.940311Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-11-09T14:32:47.940314Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2022-11-09T14:32:47.940318Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-11-09T14:32:47.940321Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-11-09T14:32:47.941004Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-11-09T14:32:47.942578Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2022-11-09T14:32:47.944596Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 4.5G, instances = 6, chunk size = 128M
2022-11-09T14:32:48.242333Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-11-09T14:32:48.300574Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-11-09T14:32:48.314983Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.356681Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 12582754923
2022-11-09T14:32:48.356724Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 12582754932
2022-11-09T14:32:48.356730Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2022-11-09T14:32:48.356733Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.655581Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-11-09T14:32:48.655606Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-11-09T14:32:48.655637Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-11-09T14:32:48.664379Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.664855Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.664863Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.665178Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-11-09T14:32:48.715827Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.25 started; log sequence number 12582754932
2022-11-09T14:32:48.716059Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-11-09T14:32:48.716491Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.726408Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2022-11-09T14:32:48.726421Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2022-11-09T14:32:48.726435Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2022-11-09T14:32:48.726454Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732596Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732630Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732636Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732640Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'debian-sys-maint@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732645Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'phpmyadmin@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732650Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'doolnews@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732664Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'linode-longview@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732836Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732847Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732851Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'phpmyadmin phpmyadmin@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.732857Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'doolnews\_pressq doolnews@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.733001Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.741232Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.741243Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-11-09T14:32:48.774110Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2022-11-09T14:32:48.774258Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2-log'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2022-11-09T14:32:58.907227Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 221109 14:32:58
```

Comment: I realise you probably don't know this, but looking at phpMyAdmin screenshots and the server configuration is not very useful when dealing with corrupted data. What you want to look at is the MySQL log file, which will tell you exactly what it thinks the problem is. Next time consider doing backups _before_ things go sideways, not after.

Comment: @mustaccio, thanks for the comment. I've updated my question adding mysql error log please have a look.

Comment: "Lost connection" is a "timeout", not a "crash".  Don't try to "recover".

Comment: Log file shows it `Starting crash recovery`, so I assume it did. The logs further back will probably show the crash. Could try dropping the indexes on `wp_posts` and re-creating them. Also check by running `dmesg` to see if OOM killed MySQL.

Comment: It was all a memory issue it seems. Simple rebooting cleanly solved the problem. Initial I was afraid to reboot.If it was a real crash and if anything more to do before a reboot to make sure a clean recovery.